# How to return a list of value from DataLayer

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my Business layer ,this code returns only a single value,
How to return a list of value from DataLayer.

```
 public class GetLocal
{
    public BusinessObj.Tables.GetLocal GetItem(int TransId)
    {
        DataLayer.PL.GetLocal objGetLocalDL = new DataLayer.PL.GetLocal();

        try
        {
            return objGetLocalDL.GetItem(TransId);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Post your code for objGetLocalDL.GetItem(), I think it returns only one value. you might need to change it or create different method ....

Comment: To return a list of `BusinessObj.Tables.GetLocal` you need to use a different method in your DAL that returns a list of these objects.Actually the code in  `objGetLocalDL.GetItem` returns one object. So a new method is required here (unless you want to renunce to the actual functionality of `objGetLocalDL.GetItem` and change it to become a `GetItems`)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Data Access Layer to create additional method E.g. GetItems to return multiple items

You can use any type of collection to get List of Items from DAL Layer.

Example using List Collection:

```
public List<BusinessObj.Tables.GetLocal> GetItems(int TransId) 
{ 
  //Your Code to Fill List Collection 
}
```

Call the above method from Business Layer to get multiple items